# python: map() two iterations with variables in map iterator

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Is there a way to include the following line as a map?

```
   alist = []
   for name in range(4):
            for sname in range(15):
                final = Do_Class(name, sname) #Is a class not to be bothered with
                alist.append(final)
```

Instead as alist.append(map(.....multiple map within maybe?))

UPDATE:

```
x = [Do_Class(name, sname) for name in xrange(15) for sname in xrange(4)]
alist = [i for i in x]
```

the above works with no error

```
alist = [i for i in Do_Class(name, sname) for name in xrange(15) for sname in xrange(4)]
```

Throws back UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sname' referenced before assignment

This has got to be the lamest thing in Python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `itertools.product` :

```
from itertools import product
alist = [Do_Class(x[0], x[1]) for x in product(range(4), range(15))]
```

if you absolutely need map :

```
alist = map(lambda x: Do_Class(x[0], x[1]), product(range(4), range(15)))
```

if you want a shorter version, but less readable:

```
alist = map(Do_Class, sorted(range(4)*15), range(15)*4)
```

### edit

need to sort the range(4)*15 to obtain 0, 0, 0, ..., 1, ... rather than 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, ...

### edit 2

I stumbled upon `itertools.starmap`, which should give something like:

```
from itertools import starmap
from itertools import product
alist = starmap(Do_Class, product(range(4), range(15)))
```

thought that was a nice solution too.

Comment: what does this do range(4)*15 ?

Comment: Almost forgot about itertools.product exactly what could fit in. but then w/o map i could use list comprehension. Is there a thing like map() vs list comprehension that map is slower? everybody seems to not use map

Comment: also, i wonder if Do_Class(x[0], x[1]) can be replaced by Do_Class(*x)

Comment: I tried that.instead x can be a dict to store multiple arguments likewise if it increases.but my problem is not so much on this as much as on my UPDATE msg where 1 list comprehension is possible and the other 'should' happen but its really surprising why its not.

Answer (score 3):

You do not want/need `map` for this:

```
alist = [Do_Class(name, sname) for sname in range(15) for name in range(4)]
```

Using `map` would only be appropriate if you could do something like `map(somefunc, somelist)`. If that's not the case you'd need a lambda which just adds unnecessary overhead compared to a list comprehension.

Comment: This is called a 'list comprehension', and this exactly the intended use for it.

Comment: throws back NameError: global name 'name' is not defined OR UnboundLocalError: local variable 'name' referenced before assignment

Comment: In general, pythonic code uses comprehensions more than `map`/`filter`.

Comment: @user2290820 do you have _both_ loops defined at the end?  `name` gets defined inside the comprehension where it says `... for name in range(4)]`

Comment: @askewchan check update above. it works for one list comprehension but not the other way

Comment: @user2290820 Are you using `name` somewhere other than in this one line?  It is assigned in the part I mentioned, and referenced by the beginning `[Do_Class(name, sname) for ...`  This is standard syntax, and it works on my computer as is.

Answer (score 0):

```
alist = map(lambda name : map(lambda sname : Do_Class(name, sname), range(15)), range(4)) #please don't do this
```

Comment: zip(range(4), range(15)) == zip(range(4), range(4)), as 15 > 4

Comment: @njzk You are correct, and also alist.append probably isn't necessary either.

Comment: I think you want something like `itertools.product()` instead of `zip()`

Comment: I think you need itertools.product rather than zip, in this case

Comment: I just went ahead and nested it.

Answer (score 0):

Why use `map` when you can simply use a `list comprehension`?

```
alist = [Do_Class(name, sname) for sname in range(15) for name in range(4)]
```

This should be sufficient and more efficient than `map`.

If you need really need `map`, you can do something like this:

```
alist = map(lambda x: Do_Class(x[0], x[1]), [(name, sname) for sname in range(15) for name in range(4)])
```